# PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, keras, apache-spark-sql, pickle

I have plan to train my model with data in spark. I changed numpy array to spark dataframe and tried to train. but I got pickle error.. I don't know why.. where or which point the serialization problem comes from.
This training tutorial works fine with the given dataset. but it's not working with my own data.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['feature','label'])
# z_train and y_train is numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['feature','label'])
for i in range(799):
    df.set_value(i,'feature',[z_train[i]])
    df.set_value(i,'label',[y_train[i]])

from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
#make 'feature' numpy array to dense vector
df['feature'] = df['feature'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
df['feature'] = df['feature'].apply(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x))
#make pandas dataframe to spark dataframe
dataset_train = reader.createDataFrame(df)
```

This is error when I trained my model in spark

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/HOME/rayjang/cnn_finetune/./pdDF.py", line 199, in <module>
    trained_model = trainer.train(training_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distkeras/trainers.py", line 638, in train
    self.history = dataset.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(worker.train).collect()
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 776, in collect
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2403, in _jrdd
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2336, in _wrap_function
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2315, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 657, in dumps
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 401, in save_instancemethod
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 535, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/HOME/rayjang/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 692, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 568, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _cffi_backend.CTypeDescr objects
```

can I get hint to solve this problem???